# Can Android Libraries in Gradle have other Android Libraries as dependencies?

Tags: android, gradle, android-library

Is this structure allowed?

```
MyProject/
 | settings.gradle
 + app/
    | build.gradle
 + libraries/
    + lib1/
       | settings.gradle
       | build.gradle
       + libraries/
          + sublib1/
             | build.gradle
          + sublib2/
             | build.gradle
    + lib2/
       | build.gradle
```

I had this working with Ant but with Gradle my project can't find sublib1 or sublib2.

*When I run gradle I get this error:*

```
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':libraries:lib1'.
> Project with path ':libraries:sublib1' could not be found in project ':libraries:lib1'.
```

This is **settings.gradle** from **MyProject**:

```
include ':libraries:lib1'
include ':libraries:lib2'
```

This is **build.gradle** from **MyProject**:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.4'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'android'

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
    compile project(':libraries:lib1')
    compile project(':libraries:lib2')
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 15
    buildToolsVersion "17.0.0"

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }

        instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')
    }
}
```

This is **settings.gradle** from **lib1**:

```
include ':libraries:sublib1'
include ':libraries:sublib2'
```

This is **build.gradle** from **lib1**:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
        compile project(':libraries:sublib1')
        compile project(':libraries:sublib2')
    }
}

apply plugin: 'android-library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 15
}
```

Comment: Did this ever work for you?

Comment: No. I gave up and went back to eclipse.

Answer (score 3):

Gradle does not seem to support several `settings.gradle` files. This file should be present only in the project root and should include all the subprojects :

```
include ':libraries:lib1', ':libraries:lib1:libraries:sublib1', ':libraries:lib1:libraries:sublib2', ':libraries:lib2'
```

Source : http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html

Comment: Would this mean that my Library projects can not have other Library projects as dependencies?

Comment: Sure they can, you juste have to include them in the settings.gradle. At least this is true from a pure Gradle point of view. Android team may add a more specific gradle task for such library project recursivity, but I didn't see anything like that so far.

Answer (score 0):

You can have other libraries as dependencies in a library project.
In your settings.gradle just include ALL the applications/libraries modules.

And in the library project that depends on another library module you just add it as a dependency just like any other module in the project.

In one of my library modules the dependency in gradle looks like this:

```
dependencies {
    compile project(':library1')
    compile project(':library2')
    compile project(':library3')
}
```